# SSH through Python with ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to create a script that uses SSH in Python to log in to a remote machine. My script is then supposed to call a certain rest API from that machine, and then returns the response to the original client.

I can't use subprocesses so that's sadly out of the question. I tried using Paramiko and Fabric but ended up having hugely complicated code segments with a lot of mandatory fields. I have setup my public key in all the steps between me and the machine and can easily go through all the intermediate machines by just typing.

"SSH xxx" - in the terminal

So what I'm looking for is something that allows me to do this simple request without me having to re-specify everything that's already setup. Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: Why can't you use subprocess? Also you can use ssh as a tunnel, maybe that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done something similar.

Here is a working sample program that uses SSH in Python to log in to a remote machine, then calls a certain rest API from that machine, then returns the response to the original client.

```
import paramiko
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import sys

my_server = sys.argv[1]

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(my_server)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(
    'curl http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/')
xml = stdout.read()
xml = ET.fromstring(xml)
assert xml.find('.//FIRSTNAME').text == 'Michael'
```

If you could use `subprocess`, here is another such program:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

my_server = sys.argv[1]

xml = subprocess.check_output([
    'ssh',
    my_server,
    'curl -s http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/'])

xml = ET.fromstring(xml)
assert xml.find('FIRSTNAME').text == 'Michael'
```